# SVG text shift/text change animation

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I'm new to SVG animation, I want to create [`this`](https://codepen.io/rachsmith/pen/BNKJme) animation in SVG, and save it as an **.svg** file. How do I do it? I can create an static SVG file in illustrator but I want to animate it.

Comment: you could get some ideas on how to do that from here: http://svg-wow.org/blog/2010/09/25/text-effects/

Comment: i'll try that once

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the range of correct answers is too broad